# Cant change the font color on asp menu in sharepoint 2013

Tags: css, sharepoint, aspmenu

I am trying to edit the navigation, which uses an asp menu control....I have done everything else apart from the font color; I just cant get it to work.

I have tried adding the StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="StaticSelectedStyle" line, and others like it. I have tried using a separate css class to the one i am using for the navigation. BUt nothing works:

Menu

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
                    id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                    StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="StaticSelectedStyle"
                    runat="server"
                    CssClass="nav"
                    ForeColor="Black"
                    EnableViewState="false"
                    DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                    UseSimpleRendering="true"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    StaticDisplayLevels="1"
                    DynamicHorizontalOffset="0"
                    AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
                    StaticPopoutImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/menudark.gif?rev=23"
                    StaticPopoutImageTextFormatString=""
                    SkipLinkText=""
                    StaticSubMenuIndent="0"

                />
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    margin-top:0px;   
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:0px;  
    width:800px;

}

.nav li{
    margin-left:20px;
    background-color:fuchsia;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
    color:White;
    text-align:center;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;

}

.nav li selected{
    color:#33CCFF;
}

.StaticSelectedStyle{
    color:aqua;
    background-color:aqua;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
.nav li a .menu-item-text, .nav li a:link .menu-item-text, .nav li a:active .menu-item-text {
    color:White !important;
}
.nav li a:hover .menu-item-text, .nav li a:visited .menu-item-text {
    color:#33CCFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work, i have spent the past 24 hours trying to change just the font color...and have had 0 luck what so ever...

Comment: It is literally juust the font color for some reason,  can edit the background color of the link a, the size of the text, but not the color

Comment: I edited my answer! I added the .menu-item-text class, I think this will work fine ;)